# How to prove that the reflection of a line (over a line) is a line? Morever, that reflections preserve angle measure?

Tags: geometry, reflection

Suppose R is the line of reflection. Given a line L. Prove that the reflection of L through R is also a line. Moreover, prove that reflections over a line preserve angle measure.

How can I go about proving this rigorously? I want to avoid using the fact that a reflection in a line is an isometry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choose three points $A<B<C$ on line $L$ and let $A'$, $B'$, $C'$ be their reflections. It is easy to prove that $\angle A'B'B=\angle ABB'$ and $\angle C'B'B=\angle CBB'$. Hence:
$$
\angle A'B'B+\angle C'B'B=\angle ABB'+\angle CBB'=180°
$$
and it follows that $A'B'C'$ are aligned.

Congruence of corresponding angles is a consequence of the congruence of corresponding triangles.

Comment: This is exactly what i wanted thank you!

Answer (score 0):

How far will you go to avoid using isometries in general?

Personally I would apply a translation and rotation to reduce to the case where $R$ is in fact the $x$-axis, i.e. $\{y=0\}$ line 
(assuming 2 dimensions for brevity). This is if you like doing things algebraically.

In this case it is easy to see what happens to a line of the form, e.g. $\{y = mx + c\}$ or even $\{x = c\}$ (these are the lines perpendicular to $R$), since the reflection then takes the form:

$$(x,y) \mapsto (x,-y)$$

and you can be explicit about everything.

For example, take a point in the line $(c,t)\in \{(c,y)| y \in \mathbb R\}$, this gets reflected onto $(c,-t)$. Allowing $t$ to vary, this again gives you the line $\{(c,y)| y \in \mathbb R\}.$

It is even easy to say things about angles also, as this can be interpreted largely as a statement about gradients.

How satisfactory is this answer?

Comment: Thanks for answering yes this helps!